# Checking if username exists in Database jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to check if the username is already taken, here is my script, which outputs "undefined". Can anyone help me, please? :)

This is in my jQuery - $("#registerusername").val() is the value of an input.

```
$.post('checkregister.php',{username: $("#registerusername").val()}, function(data){
    window.alert(data.exists);
    if(data.exists){
        window.alert("Name already found");
    }else{
        window.alert("Name NOT found");
    }
}, 'JSON');
```

This is in my checkregister.php

```
header('content-type: text/json');
if(!isset($_POST['username']))
exit;
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdatabase','root','pw000');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'");
$query->execute();
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $query->rowCount() > 0));
```

Comment: Just thought you should know that this is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) on how to properly use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You might want to strengthen your php against sql injection by 'sanitizing' the input.

Next why return JSON from the php?  It would be much simpler to just return either true or false.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdatabase','root','pw000');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'");
$query->execute();
if( $query->rowCount() > 0 ){
    echo 'true';
}
else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$.post('checkregister.php',{username: $("#registerusername").val()}, function(data){
window.alert(data);
if(data == 'true'){
    window.alert("Name already found");
}else{
    window.alert("Name NOT found");
}
});
```

edit---
You could also just return a boolean variable from php rather than a string, but either will work

Comment: Better than sanitizing would be using prepared statements correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's now working, and I learned something new :)

Comment: @Cory very true, but an easy implementation of mysql_real_escape_string will do wonders http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example..

Jquery

```
var username  = $.trim($('#username').val());

if(username != '') {
$.ajax({
url : 'localhost/phpScript.php',
data : {username : username},
dataType : 'JSON',
type : 'POST',
cache : false,

success : function(result) {
if(result == '1') { alert('Username Found.'); }
else if(result == '0') { alert('Username Not Found!'); }
},

error : function(err) {
console.log(err);
}
});
}
```

PHP/MySQL (Make sure that you escape value for user input, Before giving it to MySql)

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {    
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == '1') { 
echo '1'; 
} else { 
echo '0'; 
}
}
```